# How to make Interactive Form in SFMC to accept only one response?

Tags: marketing-cloud, interactive-email

I have an email with interactive form that sends the result to a Data Extension. However, I notice that when a subscriber has responded more than once, it records all the responses in my DE. I want to just get the latest response in my DE. Is it possible to just update the response in my DE? TIA.

Comment: Try to pass the "_SubscriberKey" as hidden field and mark it as PrimaryKey, so that you will have only 1 record per subscriber.... More details about IEF here https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/salesforce-marketing-cloud-interactive-forms-and-its-capabilities

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in this help doc : [Interactive Email Form FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_interactive_email_form_faq.htm&type=5)

> Your data extension configuration can impact how email forms write to the data extension. If your data extension doesn't have a primary key, the system adds a row upon form submission. If a primary key is defined, the system attempts an upsert to overwrite the record, but if the payload is missing any primary keys, the system generates a unique ID for the record.

So as Vishal pointed out you can do this with an hidden field, but it doens't have to be.